# PayPal PayPalConnectionException Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds

Tags: php, paypal, sdk

Really struggling with this one and wondering if anyone can suggest anything

I have a site with PayPal payments, it's been working fine for around 2 years

On Friday, I had to renew the SSL via Let's Encrypt which was fine but since then, I can't initialise a PayPal payment

The error is...

```
PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException Object
(
    [url:PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException:private] => https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment
    [data:PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException:private] => 
    [message:protected] => Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 28
    [file:protected] => vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php
    [line:protected] => 186
)
```

I run the same code locally and it all works fine

The hosting company are adament it's nothing to do with the server, and hitting the payment url via curl and ssh goes through

I have logging enabled in the PayPal api context and that just shows the url it's hitting, nothing more

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I could try to debug this?

Comment: Try `curl -v` to that url from the server's command line. And note that that v1 PayPal SDK is no longer maintained; it's been replaced by the Checkout-PHP-SDK: https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK

Comment: I've tried generating a token and hitting the payment url via curl from the server and that works fine. The token returns as expected and the payment url gives an unauthorized message which is what I expect seems I'm not sending any details. One thing I did notice though was this message: NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified) - SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA25 not sure if that's a problem or just a warning

Comment: If it connects successfully from the console, that's a warning. You'll need to debug the curl call within PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the server it was hosted on, nothing to do with the code or PayPal

Moved away from TSO (rubbish support) to a new hosting company and it all worked

Must have been something wrong with the Let's Encrypt SSL as this only started when they was renewed